# For your information or for your kind information?

Tags: indian-english, email

Forwarding mails with FYI tag was my normal practice. I got a mail from my lead with a line as " For your kind information ". Which is correct, For your information or for your kind information?

Answer (score 5):

"**For your kind information**" seams to appear only in Indian English.

The adjective "**kind**" here describes "**information**". Here's to ask then "*Can information be kind?*" or "*What is kind information?*" - this doesn't make sense. Information cannot be kind *(it can be good or bad; helpful or not, but not kind)* and therefore it is a semantically incorrect usage of the word.

The correct phrase is "**For your information**" or just **FYI** for short.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it does sound strange, and I would question the use of **kind** in this sentence. Information cannot *be* kind, but it can be given *with kindness*.

You can put 'kind' in similar greetings, such as 'kind regards' - the regards you are giving giving are kind in nature. When saying *For your information*, you are giving someone some information to 'keep' with their records, either physical or mental, so to speak. **For your kind information** makes it sound like you want to file it away with the **kind information** they own!

I do not believe *For your information* is a sentence which can be enhanced with a word such as *kind*.